# sqlplus: username/password in the first line of a sql script

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Just found that SQLPLUS would parse the first line of a sql script as connect string if I do not include the credentials when invoke sqlplus in the terminal, details are listed below:
I have a sql script named runme.sql:

```
scott/tiger@//localhost:1522/orcl

select * from dual;

exit;
```

If I invoke sqlplus as `sqlplus @runme.sql` , sqlplus could parse the first line and connect to database and run the sql. Can anyone point me to the documentation for this if there is any ? Also what are the advantages for supporting this syntax ?

Comment: OS details matter a lot. Since it depends on how you invoke the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#i1168769) is usually a good place to start. Note the [warning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#i1169374) if you supply the username/password on the command line; providing at least the password when prompted is more secure, and particularly in Unix-type environments means the credentials don't appear in the output of a `ps` command.

Putting either the password or both the username and password in a script automates that, but of course you have to then ensure that the script can't be viewed by anyone who shouldn't know the credentials.

As LalitKumarB notes in a comment, hardcoding the password anywhere is a security risk. If you're running scripts interactively then allow the slight inconveince of being prompted each time. (Which isn't really inconvenient when compared to the damage that could be done from the credentials being misused, and subsequent inconvenience of recovering, and/or finding a new job). If the script isn't being run interactively then use the scheduler rather than, say, cron. You can also use [Oracle Wallets](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e40393/asowalet.htm) for greater security without so much inconvenience.

Specifically for your query about it parsing the first line, [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#i1169374) says:

> If you do not specify logon but do specify start, SQL*Plus assumes that the first line of the script contains a valid logon.

In this context 'start' is the same as using `@` on the command line to supply the script name.

Comment: Just a thought, I would never ever hardcode password in the connection credential ;-) And not to forget how SQL Injection(though indirectly) might ruin our lives.

Comment: I like your explanation Alex, vote up from my side. If possible, as a senior, would you please, update your answer regarding my above suggestion(only if you get free, although it's weekend).